# Delphi QuickReports: Master/ Detail report

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-xe2

I need to create a QuickReport in Delphi xe that is laid out as:

+================

| Report Header

+================

+===============

|    Detail Band (Single Record, repeats)

```
     +=================

     |    Child band (Auto-stretching)
     .    
     +======================================
```

+=============================

| Report Footer (fixed size)

+=============================

Can anyone help me and give me a small example or expalin me how to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with the demos on the [QuickReports web site](http://www.qusoft.com)? There are examples for QR3 there that you can use for basics.

Comment: can you give me the link of Master/Detail demo?

Comment: @AM surely you can click the *FAQS* and *Downloads* links on the page Ken provided...

Comment: I download a master/detail demo but it's not clear how they link the band togather